# How do two different date/time formats to determine which one is later?

Tags: php, date

I'm getting date/time formats like this to compare:

```
08:18:00 07/11/2013

7/11/2013 9:11:00 AM
```

How do I convert each one of them to a format so I can write PHP like this to find out which one is a later date/time?

```
// $time1 will always be in HH:MM:SS MM/DD/YYYY format.
$time1 = "08:18:00 07/11/2013";

// $time2 will always be in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format.
$time2 = "7/11/2013 9:11:00 AM";

$time_one = $mytimeconvertdate_time_first($time1);
$time_two = $mytimeconvertdate_date_first($time2);

if ($time_two > $time_one) {
   echo "time_two is later" . "\n";
}  else {
   echo "time_one is later" . "\n";
}
```

I have tried this, but the second value doesn't contain date info:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// $time1 will always be in HH:MM:SS MM/DD/YYYY format.
$time1 = "08:18:00 07/11/2013";

// $time2 will always be in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format.
$time2 = "7/11/2013 9:11:00 AM";

$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s m/d/Y", $time1);
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y H:i:s", $time2);
var_dump($dt1);
var_dump($dt2);
if ($dt1 < $dt2) echo "The first is earlier";

?>
```

The output is:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2013-07-11 08:18:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
bool(false)
```

Corrected to:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

// Note: "One is 24-hour format while the other is 12-hour with am/pm. "

```
// $time1 will always be in HH:MM:SS MM/DD/YYYY format.
$time1 = "08:18:00 07/11/2013";

// $time2 will always be in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format. 
$time2 = "7/11/2013 9:11:00 AM";

$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s m/d/Y", $time1);
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $time2);
var_dump($dt1);
var_dump($dt2);
if ($dt1 < $dt2) echo "The first is earlier" . "\n";

?>


object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2013-07-11 08:18:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2013-07-11 09:11:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
The first is earlier
```

Comment: Use strtotime() function.for reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: [Carbon's](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-comparison) Comparison feature makes this easy. It's a simple API extension for DateTime with PHP 5.3+ .

Comment: @MarkusHofmann It is simple enough with the DateTime class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create two `DateTime` instances from the formatted text. You can then compare the instances directly to find which is earlier in time.

```
$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s m/d/Y", $time1);
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $time2);

if ($dt1 < $dt2) echo "The first is earlier";
// etc
```

Comment: Would that make strtotime unneeded?

Comment: @Edward: Yes it would. IMHO `strtotime` is a remnant of an unfortunate age where it was customary to rely on functions that do "magic". It's better to make everything explicit: this is a date, it's in this format, please convert it.

Comment: OK. I see a problem with this. I will post it above in a minute.

Comment: @Edward: I had made a mistake in the second format, which is now corrected above. In my defense, your comment "time2 will always be in the format..." is wrong. That's not the format your data is in. :-)

Comment: Thanks! You are correct, the house is without a leading zero. I thought about that, but wasn't sure how to express at the time. I have corrected it above with your help and now have it working. Thanks!

Comment: @Edward: The problem is not the leading zero, if you look at the formats both `g` and `h` have no problem with the zero. The issue is that one is 24-hour format while the other is 12-hour with am/pm.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Carbon (which is an API for PHP's native DateTime)](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-comparison) you could simply do:

```
<?php
$time_one = Carbon::create(2013, 11, 7, 8, 18, 00); // 08:18:00 07/11/2013
$time_two = Carbon::create(2013, 11, 7, 9, 11, 00); // 7/11/2013 9:11:00 AM

if ($time_two->gt($time_one))
{
   echo "time_two is later\n";
}
else
{
   echo "time_one is later\n";
}
```

EDIT:

Of course, you don't need to use carbon to achieve the desired result. But have a look at [the source of Carbon on GitHub](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/Carbon/Carbon.php) to see how it's done and you'll learn how to get to your goal with some examples. This is just well-intentioned advice.

Comment: Why use an (IMO pointless) API like this to solve such a trivial problem?

Comment: I'm using it together with Laravel 4 and have had good experience with it so far. I just mentioned this as it has got more functionality related to date comparisons that I find advisable for Edward.

Comment: Thanks, Markus. This helped me out using Carbon. Somehow I missed that section and was trying to find a way to export the date object from Carbon for a normal <= comparison between two dates.

Comment: @RedGlobe The [Carbon API Documentation](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api) on GitHub provides a lot of examples for many use cases. BTW.: Glad it helped you out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s", strtotime("08:18:00 07/11/2013"));
$date2 = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s", strtotime("08:18:00 07/11/2013"));

if($date2 > $date1)
    ...
```