# Datetime is before or after datetime

Tags: php, datetime, compare

I have two strings like this:

```
$stringA = '2017-05-05 12:06:00';
$stringB = '2017-04-05 16:32:00';
```

How can I see if `$stringB` is before or after `$stringA`?

I was thinking something like this:

```
if($stringB > stringA) {
    echo "string B is still in the future!";
}
```

Comment: Hope my post will help you out..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do two different date/time formats to determine which one is later?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590926/how-do-two-different-date-time-formats-to-determine-which-one-is-later)

Answer (score 2):

Here we are using `strtotime` to convert time to no. of seconds, and we are comparing no. of seconds of both the dates.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/788117)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$stringA = "2017-05-05 12:06:00";
$stringB = "2017-04-05 16:32:00";
if(strtotime($stringA) > strtotime($stringB))
{
    echo "Before is ".$stringB;
}
else
{
    echo "Before is ".$stringA;
}
```

**Output:** `Before is 2017-04-05 16:32:00`

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can use the `DateTime` or the `DateTimeImmutable` object.

```
    $dateTimeA = new DateTimeImmutable('2017-05-05 12:06:00');
    $dateTimeB = new DateTimeImmutable('2017-04-05 16:32:00');
```

then you will be able to do what you just wrote safely

```
    if ($dateTimeB > $dateTimeA) {
        echo "string B is still in the future!";
    }
```